# HAproxy - Redirect issue - Uri Variables?

Tags: linux, web-server, haproxy

I'm using haproxy 1.5dev3 and I was wondering if there is any possible way to grab uri variables from a request to reappend the query on the end of a redirect url?

What I'm trying to do is redirect from:

http://www.domain.com/page/example.htm?id=1234567

to:

http://www.domain.com/frame/newpage.cfm?id=1234567

redirect prefix doesn't work properly as it tries to append /page/example.htm to the end of the redirect url. Can I do some sort of rewrite to accomplish this? It would be awesome if you could use uri and queries as variables for redirection/pool selection like on F5. Please help...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such feature yet, and now I doubt it will be available before 1.5 is released.